# does using remove on iterator makes code to work very slow?

Tags: java, iterator

I have a code as follows, it uses remove on a iterator as show:

```
Collection<X> getdata(){
   Collection<X> Xs = this.getXs();
    Iterator<X> iterator = Xs.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        X x = iterator.next();
        if (somecondition) {
            iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }

 return Xs;
}
```

It works some times and sometime it takes very long time, and my thread hangs. getXs method returns data from DB.

Comment: insufficient information

Comment: What else information is needed?

Comment: Which lines of code are slow? getXs() accessing DB is slow? or 'somecondition' is complex? or ORM collection used?

Comment: What kind of Collection do you use?

Comment: If `Xs` is in some way bound to the database itself (i.e. calling `remove()` on it or its iterator actually removes a row from the DB), then `remove()` can be an expensive operation (but shouldn't be more expensive than `remove()` on the `Collection` itself). Basically: what org.life.java said!

Comment: Something is not good on your code: is that your are modifying a list while looping on it. It is not guarantied that it is harmless.

Comment: I guess it all depends on actual type of `Collection` and its iterator.

Comment: @Joachim.How can Xs be bound to DB? There are returned from Db by using a entity manager and that entitymanager is closed after returning.Can you please elobarate?

Comment: (If `getXs` returns, say, an `ArrayList` then for a constant density of matches the remove will cause the algorithm to be O(n^2). Bad news for large n, irrelevant for small n. A lazy (or blocking/deadlocking/starving/something) iterator seems a more likely situation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iteration and removal won't have the abnormal behavior you describe in and of itself. There are other, environmental conditions at work. Since you describe interacting with a database, chances are good that the delays and hangs are related to the way your code is interacting with the data. There are countless variations on what may be the actual problem, so any additional detail you can provide (as opposed to the very general example you posted) will be helpful in troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: thanks.I will ry to modify the code and check.Will get back in some time